# What are the fast request get url library's in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, request

I want to send get and post requests to an external site. With which library can I get the returned json data fastest?

Comment: Have you tried any? Can you add code trying two and measuring the time of each?

Comment: I found this 
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/req-fast 
but i haven't tried. I want to learn if there is a popular method